# Текстовый файл содержит слова. Заключить слова, начинающиеся с согласной буквы в двойные кавычки

Tags: c, файлы, строки

Задача звучит так:

> Текстовый файл содержит слова. Заключить слова, начинающиеся с согласной буквы в  двойные кавычки.

Собственно, как я пытаюсь ее решить:
Считываем посимвольно текст в массив символов, если символ заглавный, тогда пустой переменной присваиваем текущий элемент, текущему элементу открывающую кавычку, следующему элементу - переменную, и следующей - закрывающую кавычку, и так с каждым элементом в цикле. Проблема в том, что компилятор ругается на строку "if(a[i] == "A","B")" пишет следующее:

> have incompatible types 'char' and 'char *'

До этого часто писал на php и там подобных проблем не было.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char a[1000];
int count=0;
FILE *file = fopen("1.txt", "rw");
for(int i=0;!feof(file);i++){
      a[i]=fgetc(file);
    if(a[i] == 'A'){

    }
    count++;
}
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
printf("%c",a[i]);
}
fclose(file);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнить символ (`a[i]`) с указателем на символы (`"A"` (да, строковая константа это массив символов и значит в некотором смысле указатель)), вот на это компилятор и ругается. Ну, и  даже если написать синтаксически правильно `if (a[i] == 'A','B')`, то это будет не то, что вы хотели.

Comment: Это и так понятно, как это исправить?

Comment: Учтите, что еще вы неверно используете `feof`. И последнее - не стоит исправлять **в вопросе** код на верный: вы ставите всех в дурацкое положение, в том числе себя: спрашиваете, почему не работает правильный код...

Comment: именно этот код, который представлен выдает именно ту ошибку, которая написана

Answer (score 1):

Если это

```
if(a[i] == "A","B")
```

должно означать `a[i]` или `A`, или `B`, то

```
if (a[i] == 'A' || a[i] == 'B')
```

или

```
if (strchr("AB",a[i]))
```

Если нет - поясните, что именно вы хотели выразить этой конструкцией...

Вот примерное решение вашей задачи:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int isConsonant(int c)
{
    static char consonants[] = "BCDFGHKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
    return strchr(consonants,toupper(c)) != NULL;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * in = fopen("1.txt","r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int word = 0, c = getc(in); c != EOF; c = getc(in)) {
        if (word) {
            if (isspace(c) || ispunct(c)) {
                if (word == 1) putchar('"');
                word = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (!isspace(c) && (1 == (word = (isConsonant(c) ? 1 : 2)))) putchar('"');
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

Comment: символ является заглавным или нет. я знаю, что там неправильно написано, если вам будет проще, представьте, что там нет "B", от этого ничего не измениться

Comment: @ВадимМороз, а где вы нашли что сравнение должно делаться именно так, как в вашем коде? Ваша конструкция к языку C не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я написал вам, как надо поступить. Обратите внимание на **одинарные** кавычки.

Comment: Я же сказал, что знаю, что неправильно написал, суть ошибки не в этом была и я сказал об этом. Проблема была именно в указателе, в том что элементу массива нельзя было присваивать символ, решается это через переменную.

Comment: Через какую переменную? Вы сделали, как я и писал - через одинарные кавычки...